# Unable to re-install LibreOffice after software update proposed by Ubuntu

Tags: updates, libreoffice

Since I installed Ubuntu20.04 I always used Libreoffice (LO).
After a general software update proposed by Ubuntu, I wasn't able to open .odt docs.
I tried to uninstall LO via the software center ('Remove'), and to re-install. No go! I even still could start Writer and Calc... loosing connection with the storage disks.
I scanned - for as far as possible (I'm visually impaired) - the web and tried several advised methods/commands to purge, remove, etc. Still no normal LO. Maybe I missed something. Anyway, I managed to re-install LO... but still no connection with the storage partition.
Can please someone give me a hint: I need this tool for my one-man-enterprise.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you are "*loosing connection with the storage disks*", then I would ask about that problem. Did you run a SMART test on those disks? If not, look up how to do so.

Comment: @user53573 Did a SMART test. Disk is OK but one remark: end-to-end-error that got 'failed'. Disk(s) were detectable before and after starting LibreOffice. "Were", because yet I can't even start up LO.  Besides, never got problems before the update, neither when not using LO.

Comment: A SMART result showing end-to-end failure seems the opposite of 'OK'. It's bad news. It often means that your disk is no longer reliable and perhaps near-death.

Comment: @user535733: OK! That means a new desktop... Thanks a lot for your advice! Have a nice day!